# Data is loading in redux state but not getting rendered on screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

So I am rendering a simple post list in React.js using react-redux with axios
The data is coming from Laravel API
I have no idea what to do. I have posted my code below!
postActions.js file

```
export const authUserPosts = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_LIST_REQUEST,
    });

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();

    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.meta.token}`,
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.get('api/v1/posts', config);

    dispatch({
      type: POST_LIST_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_LIST_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

postReducer.js

```
export const postAuthUserReducer = (state = { posts: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case POST_LIST_REQUEST:
      return {
        loading: true,
      };
    case POST_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        posts: action.payload,
      };
    case POST_LIST_FAIL:
      return {
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Data is loaded in redux state and here's the screenshot of it

[image: Text]

I am mapping this data inside my PostScreen.js like this.

```
{posts.map((element) => (
   <div className="mb-4" key={element.id}>
   <div>
   <Link to="/" className="font-bold">
     {element.body}
   </Link>

   <span className="text-gray-600 text-small ml-20">
     {element.created_at}
   </span>

    <Link to="/" className="bg-red-500">
       Delete
     </Link>
    </div>

     <p className="mb-2"></p>
   </div>
))}
```

I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: Answer in the below, should actually work. How do you get the posts from the redux state? Did you check it? If you believe so, try posts?.data.map() or post.data && post.data.map etc.

Answer (score 0):

you have `data` object inside `posts`. `posts.data.map` will work.

Comment: TypeError: posts.data is undefined

Comment: Before mapping, check if `posts` exists, `posts.data` exists, and `posts.data.length > 0`. If any one of those conditions is `false`, no array is present to map.